# Integer matrices with integer inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, unimodular-matrices

If all entries of an invertible matrix $A$ are rational, then all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are also rational. Now suppose that all entries of an invertible matrix $A$ are integers. Then it's not necessary that all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are integers. My question is:

> What are all the invertible integer matrices such that their inverses are also integer matrices?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Exactly those whose determinant is $1$ or $-1$.

See [the previous question about the $2\times 2$ case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/units-of-m-2z/3659#3659). The determinant map gives necessity, the adjugate formula for the inverse gives sufficiency.

Comment: We find this statement everywhere on the web, but it's only for n > 1. For 1x1 matrices, all matrices are invertible except [0].

Comment: @jherek: The question is when are matrices with integer coefficients invertible with an inverse that has **integer** coefficients. The matrix $[2]$ may be invertible, but the inverse does not have integer coefficients. What integers have an integer multiplicative inverse? Exactly $1$ and $-1$. So your statement is either incorrect (if you think you are correcting what I wrote) or irrelevant (answering the question of which matrices have inverses, instead of which integer matrices have *integer matrix* inverse). Which is it?

Answer (score 13):

The inverse of an integer matrix is again an integer matrix iff if the determinant of the matrix is $\pm 1$. Integer matrices of determinant $\pm 1$ form the General Linear Group $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: Very interesting  statement. Is it not possible to generate integer inverse for matrix with determinant for example $2$ ? Quite surprising but probably the statement is true.

Answer (score 8):

Arturo and Sivaram have already given the general condition for integer matrices with integer inverses; here I only note this particular example due to [Ericksen](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0717041) that the matrix $\mathbf A$ with entries

$$a_{ij}=\binom{n+j-1}{i-1}$$

where $n$ is an arbitrary nonnegative integer has an integer inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment, a picture of a particularly simple one:

[image]

Added: 
Iterative solvers have a hard time solving $Ax = b$ with
$b$ a point source $[0 0 0 ... 1 ... 0 0 0]$:

$A^{-1} b$ has to pick out a column of $A^{-1}, \pm \, [1 \, 0 \, -1 \, 0 ...]$.
Also, this $A$ is far from positive-definite -- its eigenvalues are symmetric about $0$.

See also
[gmres-for-a-non-diagonalizable-matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33724/how-does-gmres-method-iteration-behave-for-this-non-diagonalizable-matrix/36993#36993)
on scicomp.stack .

Answer (score 0):

$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{|A|}C^T
$$
Where $|A|$ denotes the determinant of matrix $A$ and $C$ is the matrix of minors.  Each entry in $C^T$, $c_{ji}$, represents the minor removing just the $i$th row and the $j$th column. Each of these determinants is the sum, difference and multiple of integers, so each $c_{ji}$ is integer. This means, of course, that $|A|$ must be $\pm 1$. Since matrices may be of any integer dimension and there are infinite integers, just listing the identity matrices gets us to $\infty$.