# Inverse of matrix has to have integer elements

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a matrix say $A$ with integer elements. I want to have the elements of $A^{-1}$ to be integers . Here $A^{-1}$ stands for inverse matrix of $A$ . How can I prove that this is achievable iff the determinant value of $A$ is unimodular?

Comment: I have only noticed that if determinant value is +1 or -1 then the situation is true.

Comment: Cramer's rule${}$?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit @Lord Shark The Unknown?

Comment: @Jose I want to prove it for an $n×n$ matrix, the link you have given is only showing the proof for a $2×2$, I guess.

Comment: @AkashRoy That's the question, but did you actually read [the first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3659/446262)?

Comment: @Jose Carlos , I have got the answer. But how can I prove it using Cramer's rule as mentioned above by Lord Shark?

Comment: I only see how to apply Cramer's rule to prove that **if** $M$ has integer coefficients and its determinant is $\pm1$, **then** $M^{-1}$ has integer coefficients, but not in the opposite direction.

Comment: An illustration would have helped me more , but I will try to manage if you can tell me how to start about it. Thanks in advance @Jose

Comment: You have $M.M^{-1}=\operatorname{Id}$. Therefore, if $v$ is the first column of $M^{-1}$, then $M.v=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$. So, $v$ can be computed by Cramer's rule. Since $\det M=\pm1$, $v$ will have integer coefficients. A similar argumen applies to the other columns.

Comment: Thank you @Jose got your approach easily!